# How to sort two arrays with one being sorted based on the sorting of the other?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mapping

So I have encountered this problem a lot of times. Let me explain. Say I have these two arrays:
`A1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};` and
`A2={1,2,3,0,2,1,1,0,0,0};`. What I require is this:
When I sort A2, whatever swapping and shifting of elements takes place in A2, the same should take place in A1 as well. Basically I am trying to create a Map using two arrays instead of creating an actual HashMap or HashTable.

Finally the arrays should look like this:
`A1={4,8,9,10,1,6,7,2,5,3};` and `A2={0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3};`. The corresponding values of both arrays are still the same but the data is sorted based on A2. I need a way to do this kind of sort in the fastest way possible.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Smells like the [parallel collections anti-pattern](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). You can resolve this by defining a new class with two fields; one field is an element from A1 and the other field is the corresponding element from A2. Instead of two arrays, use a single array of instances of your new class. Then you can sort the array using a comparator that only considers the field that used to be the element from A2.

Comment: Declare arrays of size 2 inside an array of size N and sort based on 2nd index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pair Class could do the trick here.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>
    {
        int a1;
        int a2;
        Pair (int a1, int a2) //constructor 
        {
            this.a1 = a1;
            this.a2 = a2;
        }
        public int compareTo(Pair other) //making it only compare a2 values
        {
            return this.a2 - other.a2;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] A1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int[] A2 = {1,2,3,0,2,1,1,0,0,0};
        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[A1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
        {
            pairs[i] = new Pair(A1[i], A2[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(pairs);
        //printing values 
        for (int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(pairs[i].a1 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < A2.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(pairs[i].a2 + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

By making a Pair class that holds 2 variables `a1` and `a2`, you can override the `compareTo` method to only compare the `a2` value, so that when `Arrays.sort` is called, the pairs in the Pair array will be swapped only according to the `a2` values. You can then access the values in the pairs and print them out. This will produce your desired output.

Comment: @Sankeenth Ganeswaran Thanks a ton! I'm sure this will do the job. Cheers!

Comment: And if it's three arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorting three arrays based on the ordering of just one of them? That would simply require making the Pair class have a third attribute a3.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a two-dimensional array where each element is an array of length `2` and sort it based on the second element.

```
int[] A1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, A2 = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
final int[][] res = new int[A1.length][2];
for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    res[i] = new int[] {A1[i], A2[i]};
}
Arrays.sort(res, (a,b)->Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]));
//Alternatively, Arrays.sort(res, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[1]));
for(final int[] a : res) {
    System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes I think this will work too. And seems more easier. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AkshatJ. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating an object based on the data that you actually have. In this case the object might contain two fields, numbers and occurrences. Then implement a comparator to compare by the occurrences field.